# Confusion in using OAuth in reactjs and react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a question, let's say I have a website (reactjs) and app (react-native) both using OAuth facebook login. Should I save the access token provided by facebook in my database and if I should, what will happen to the access token when user logins with facebook on website and then login again with the app?

Does that mean access token is going to be overwritten by new login? Do you have any other suggestions for good practice for OAuth integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth token of 2 consecutive logins are different. I would still store them in the database but not as a 1:1 relationship to the user bot as 1:n. This means every user can have multiple OAuth tokens assigned.

In OAuth you also get back the expiration of a token. You can store that one as well and clean up the table if needed.

For mongoDB again directly in the answer for better readability:
You can design your user collection like this:

```
{
    "_id": 42,
    "username": "jeger",
    "token": [
        {"value": "abc1234", "expiration": ...}
        {"value": "bca4321", "expiration": ...}
    ]
}
```

And search the user after token verification to facebook with

```
collection.find({"token.value": "abc1234"})
```

Comment: so, I should make 2 entities in database for access token one for web and one for mobile? and Thanks

Comment: I would suggest 2 entities. One for Users and the other one for tokens with a 1:n relation. Keep in mind, that users can be logged in from multiple browsers as well.

Comment: so, in terms of Mongodb two different collection one for user and one for token?

Comment: I had relational databases in mind. In mongoDB that depends on your preference. You could also just add a list of tokens to your user document. I can provide an example as soon as I'm home from work. (~06:00 PM CEST)

Comment: Corrected my answer a bit to reflect your need (mongodb) a bit better :)